# Deleted content returns over and over again

Tags: nodes, database

I have a situation where I can delete (update options > delete selected content) in admin > content...and it says it deletes all the selected records.

But then later on all those records will return again. After I delete them they are not showing at all in (admin > content). But then later, they will show up again there and the links will be clickable etc. It will be like I never deleted them. I can do this over and over again and they keep re-appearing. We're talking about 50 nodes here.

I haven't updated the database otherwise. I've gone to a page (such as search) where those used to appear and they appear again there...and sometimes it seems like maybe that has something to do with it. But I still don't understand what or why.

Is there a better way to delete content to ensure its completely gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the error log? is there any warning or error in there?

If not then you should manually delete it from database. just look for their ID and remove them from DB

Comment: I appreciate the thought and I'm not sure where the error log is? But I've deleted about 64 nodes over and over again from find content > selected them all and deleted them. Then a few days later they will just show up again in the database as if nothing happened. Moreover after I delete them they are no longer in the nodes table...so I have no idea what's going on. I also find when I try to re-add one of those items it messes up some of my site functionality. If I add a totally new item my site works fine. So somehow those ghost entries are hurting me..

Comment: your site is on localhost or remote server?

Comment: on localhost. Does that matter?